# Duplicate fn:analyze-string() output using xsl:analyze-string?

Tags: regex, xslt, xpath

Is it possible to generate output identical to the `fn:analyze-string` (XPath 3.0)  using `xsl:analyze-string` (XSLT 2.0)?

Some examples for input string `abcdefg`:

1. `regex="^a((b(c))d)(efg)$"`

   ```
   <s:analyze-string-result xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2009/xpath-functions/analyze-string">
       <s:match>a<s:group nr="1">
           <s:group nr="2">b<s:group nr="3">c</s:group>
           </s:group>d</s:group>
           <s:group nr="4">efg</s:group>
       </s:match>
   </s:analyze-string-result>
   ```
2. `regex="^((a(bc)d)(.*))$`

   ```
   <s:analyze-string-result xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2009/xpath-functions/analyze-string">
       <s:match>
           <s:group nr="1">
               <s:group nr="2">a<s:group nr="3">bc</s:group>d</s:group>
               <s:group nr="4">efg</s:group>
           </s:group>
       </s:match>
   </s:analyze-string-result>
   ```
3. `regex="^(((a)(b)(cde)(.*)))$"`

   ```
   <s:analyze-string-result xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2009/xpath-functions/analyze-string">
       <s:match>
           <s:group nr="1">
               <s:group nr="2">
                   <s:group nr="3">a</s:group>
                   <s:group nr="4">b</s:group>
                   <s:group nr="5">cde</s:group>
                   <s:group nr="6">fg</s:group>
               </s:group>
           </s:group>
       </s:match>
   </s:analyze-string-result>
   ```

I suspect it's not possible because `xsl:analyze-string` does not provide methods to: 1) know how many groups there, or 2) discover parent/child relationships of groups to facilitate recursion. But I'm curious if there is something I have overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a bit easier by changing the syntax of the regex, using `<g>  </g>` for grouping rather than `()`  (it would be possible but tiresome not to do this and instead analyse the regex and determine the groups)

Once you have the group structure you can generate the normal regex using `()` to pass to `xsl:analyze-function` adding extra groups so that every text run is grouped and can be retrieved later with `regex-group()`.

Not extensively tested so there may be bugs but something like this, and it seems to work on your examples.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:f="data:,f"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
        >

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:function name="f:analyze-string">
 <xsl:param name="s"/>
 <xsl:param name="r"/>
 <xsl:variable name="rr">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="a-s" select="$r"/>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
 <f:analyze-string-result>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:analyze-string select="$s" regex="{$rr}">
   <xsl:matching-substring>
    <f:match>
     <xsl:variable name="m" select="."/>
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="g" select="$r"/>
    </f:match>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:matching-substring>
   <xsl:non-matching-substring>
    <f:non-match>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </f:non-match>
   </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
 </f:analyze-string-result>
 <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template mode="a-s" match="g">
 <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="a-s"/>
 <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="a-s" match="text()[../g]">
 <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="g" match="g">
 <f:group>
  <xsl:attribute name="nr">
   <xsl:number level="any"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="g"/>
 </f:group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="g" match="text()">
 <xsl:variable name="n">
  <xsl:number count="g|text()[../g]" level="any"/>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(xs:integer($n))"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="main">

 <!-- regex="^a((b(c))d)(efg)$" -->
 <xsl:variable name="r">a<g><g>b<g>c</g></g>d</g><g>efg</g>$</xsl:variable>
 <xsl:sequence  select="f:analyze-string('abcdefg',$r)"/>

 <!-- regex="^((a(bc)d)(.*))$ -->
 <xsl:variable name="r"><g><g>a<g>bc</g>d</g><g>.*</g></g>$</xsl:variable>
 <xsl:sequence  select="f:analyze-string('abcdefg',$r)"/>


<!-- regex="^(((a)(b)(cde)(.*)))$" -->
 <xsl:variable name="r"><g><g><g>a</g><g>b</g><g>cde</g><g>.*</g></g></g>$</xsl:variable>
 <xsl:sequence  select="f:analyze-string('abcdefg',$r)"/>


</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces

```
$ saxon9 -it main analyse.xsl

<f:analyze-string-result xmlns:f="data:,f">
<f:match>a<f:group nr="1"><f:group nr="2">b<f:group nr="3">c</f:group></f:group>d</f:group><f:group nr="4">efg</f:group></f:match>

</f:analyze-string-result>

<f:analyze-string-result xmlns:f="data:,f">
<f:match><f:group nr="1"><f:group nr="2">a<f:group nr="3">bc</f:group>d</f:group><f:group nr="4">efg</f:group></f:group></f:match>

</f:analyze-string-result>

<f:analyze-string-result xmlns:f="data:,f">
<f:match><f:group nr="1"><f:group nr="2"><f:group nr="3">a</f:group><f:group nr="4">b</f:group><f:group nr="5">cde</f:group><f:group nr="6">fg</f:group></f:group></f:group></f:match>

</f:analyze-string-result>
```